# Next/previous anchor link, how to update the next/previous links when the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First time posting here! Stack overflow told me to include the code from codepen.io so I did, but I think the actual link is more useful than reading the code from here.

I applied this http://codepen.io/haustraliaer/pen/leKny/ javascript code to my websites and it works great. I want scrolling past the pages to update the links so that when i scroll down and click next, it doesn't go back up where the previous anchor link lies.

I tried using scroll event and getBoundingClientRect but it seems that I can't get it to work like that.

Any help towards to solution would help me greatly.

Here is link to my homepages http://quki.kapsi.fi/wasd

```
$('.js-scroll-to').click(function(e) {

    target = $($(this).attr('href'));

    if (target.offset()) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
        }, 600);
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.js-next').click(function(e) {

    var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
    var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

    var pos = anchors.index(selected);
    var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
    var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);

    target = $(next);

    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
    $(next).addClass("js-current-panel");

    if (target.offset()) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
        }, 600);
    }


    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.js-prev').click(function(e) {

    var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
    var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

    var pos = anchors.index(selected);
    var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
    var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);

    target = $(prev);

    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
    $(prev).addClass("js-current-panel");

    if (target.offset()) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
        }, 600);
    }


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i think you are looking for fullPage.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-scroll-to').click(function(e) {

  target = $($(this).attr('href'));

  if (target.offset()) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
    }, 600);
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.js-next').click(function(e) {
  $('.js-prev').show();
  var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
  var anchors = $(".js-list-item");
  var pos = anchors.index(selected);
  var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
  var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);
  if (pos <= 4) {
    target = $(next);
    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
    $(next).addClass("js-current-panel");
    if (target.offset()) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
      }, 600);
    }
    if (pos == 4)
      $('.js-next').hide();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.js-prev').click(function(e) {
  $('.js-next').show();
  var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
  var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

  var pos = anchors.index(selected);
  var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
  var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);
  console.log(pos)
  if (pos > 0) {
    target = $(prev);

    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
    $(prev).addClass("js-current-panel");

    if (target.offset()) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
      }, 600);
    }
  }
  if (pos == 1) {
    $('.js-prev').hide();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Below is the working Example

http://codepen.io/krishnareddy668/pen/MyqwJz

Comment: I now think I did bad job describing what I want. 

What I want is:
1. The current system works as intended
2. Mouse scrolling past anchors updates the current position to the jquery script
3. When I decide to scroll down past articles and then suddenly want to move with the clickable button, it should go further down - not up

I hope I'll get better with explaining stuff. Your work is useful though, so no work in vain!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think you are looking for fullPage.js

Comment: I have been using that earlier and I think that would be the easy solution for my problem!